# Foreign Key to multiple tables TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using TypeOrm and nestJs to build a small project.

I have this 3 relevant tables in my database.

**Adress Entity**

```
import { BaseEntity } from '../../common/model/base.entity';
import { Owner } from './owner.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'address' })
export class Address extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  country: string;

  @Column()
  city: string;

  @Column()
  street: string;

  @Column({ name: 'zip_code' })
  zipCode: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'additional_description',
    nullable: true,
  })
  additionalDescription: string;

  // @ManyToOne(() => Owner) --> not working because owner isn't a table
  @Column(() => Owner)
  owner: Owner; // --> can be either a User or a Store
}
```

**Store Entity**

```
@Entity({ name: 'store' })
export class Store extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  description: string;

  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: UserEntity;

  @Column('uuid', {
    name: 'parent_id',
    nullable: true,
  })
  parentId: string;
}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({
    name: 'first_name',
    nullable: true,
  })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'last_name',
    nullable: true,
  })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'phone_number',
    nullable: true,
  })
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  gender: Gender;

  @OneToOne(() => Auth, (auth) => auth.user)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'auth_id' })
  auth: Auth;
}
```

**Base Entity**

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    name: 'created_at',
    type: 'timestamptz',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: 'updated_at',
    type: 'timestamptz',
  })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

An address can be owned by either a User or a Store via the Address.owner field.

I want to model an entity that acts as a base for both Users and Stores and have address owned by that entity.

Can somebody please guide me on how to achieve it ?

**P.S :** Even though they may solve my issue, I don't want to create 2 column `store_id` and `user_id` in the Address Entity and Also don't want it to be a `@ManyToMany` relationship.